# Robolectric Resources$NotFoundException with getBoolean() and getInteger()

Tags: android, robolectric

I have set up robolectric unit tests for my app and encountered a Problem with integer and boolean resources defined in XML. I have my tests in a separate project, but set the working directory to the project under test as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19043713/robolectric-notfoundexception-unknown-resource-0-at-org-robolectric-shadows-sh). Robolectric seems to find some of the resources correctly, because `getString(...)` and `getDrawable(...)` work fine. However, `getBoolean(...)` and `getInteger(...)` fail with a `Resources$NotFoundException`.

I dumbed down one of the test cases to reproduce the behaviour:

```
@Test
public void testResources() {

    TestActivity activity = controller.get();
    String theString = activity.getString(R.string.ab_request); // works
    Drawable theDrawable = activity.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ab_back); // works
    boolean theBool = activity.getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isRelease); // fails
    int theInt = activity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.act_noNetwork); // fails
}
```

Is this a known bug with Robolectric? I searched for a while and didn't find anyone with the same problem.

**Update**
It seems it has something to do with my `res` folder. I started from a fresh Android project, and the single test above. I then added my project dependencies: the test still ran. I copied my `res` folder to the new project: the test failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. It turns out that Robolectric [does not support the item tag](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/830) for resources declared in XML. My resources were declared as

```
<item type="bool" name="isRelease">false</item>
<item type="integer" name="act_noNetwork">12345</item>
```

However, the Robolectric XML parser just checks for `bool` nodes, and not for `item` nodes, when parsing booleans. The same goes for integers, I haven't checked other types. I changed my declarations to:

```
<bool name="isRelease">false</bool>
<integer name="act_noNetwork">12345</integer>
```

Now Robolectric parses the resources correctly. Note that both ways seem to be equally valid in the normal Android runtime. I didn't check the official docs if there is any recommendation though.